# Can I create an Intellij changelist from a task based upon a mask?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, intellij-idea, mylyn

Using Mylyn in Eclipse, there is a global setting allowing me to set a mask for the commit comments to be generated for VC commits for a task.

Is there any way to do this in IntelliJ (using 11.1.3 at the moment)?

Basically, under 'Mylyn | Team', I set the 'Commit Comment Template' to `[${task.key}] ${task.description} - ${task.url}`.

When I then commit changes for a task, Eclipse automatically generates a commit comment with the variables filled in.

In Intellij, I want the default comment for a changeset (when generated for a task) to be set in the same manner.

This is needed because we need to link commits to the JIRA task they were for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is available at Project Settings -> Tasks -> Servers -> Commit Message tab.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Do I need to stop using the Atlassian plugin when generating task changesets??? If so, is there a browser window for selection of tasks?